# Text and tint color of back button of navigation bar

Tags: iphone, colors, uinavigationbar

How can I put silver with black text of `back button` of `navigation bar` in `ios6`? please answer quick.

Comment: Did you get the slution?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarShadow"]];
```

also refer to [this tutorial](https://github.com/woelfelm/Surf-s-Up---Starter/tree/master/Surf%27s%20Up), It'll help you a lot.